# Retrieve data from Google Cloud Storage in PHP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using following php code to retrieve data from Google Cloud Storage.

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use Superbalist\Flysystem\GoogleStorage\GoogleStorageAdapter;
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Storage;

require '/vendor/autoload.php';

$storage = new StorageClient([
   'projectId' => 'project_id'
 ]);

$bucket = $storage->bucket('bucketname.domain.com');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("API_Cloud_Storage");
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials(); 
$client->setScopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]);
$service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);

$object = $service->objects->get($bucket, $storage);
$request = new Google_Http_Request($object->getMediaLink());
$response = $client->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
$body = $response->getResponseBody();
print_r($body);
```

Error I got using above code:

> {"code":400,"status":"badrequest","message":"Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information","payload":{},"session":null}

Comment: why are you using 'bucketname.domain.com' instead of '$bucketname'? You can see here some examples on [how to interact using the API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/src)

Comment: Have you tried changing `$object = $service->objects->listObjects('bucketname.domain.com', $storage);` to `$object = $service->objects->listObjects($bucket, $storage);`?

Comment: @RivaPortman Yes i already tried this but got same error message.

Comment: At which point is this error happening?